# Why does plt.plot() plots different graph for a numpy array and a numpy matrix

Tags: python, matplotlib

When I try to plot a graph with `matplotlib`, I'm unable to plot the `numpy` array properly but the `numpy` matrix works, despite the data is the same.

The file is a `.dat` file. And part of it is like this. I'm sorry that some data with exponential isn't properly displayed:

```
   13.589515189014234       0.15604292500000005     
   13.735639008250946       0.15257472499999994     
   13.881762827487661       0.14755997499999998     
   14.027886646724372       0.14034605000000008     
   14.174010465961084       0.13002836249999997     
   14.320134285197797       0.11536830749999996     
   14.466258104434509       0.09470843482500003    
   15.343001019854782      -0.29482481522500004     
   15.489124839091494      -0.41008690550000004     
   15.635248658328205      -0.50755824292125018     
   15.781372477564917      -0.55349056577499989     
   15.927496296801632      -0.52813589407000028     
   16.073620116038342      -0.44291128949999964     
   16.219743935275055      -0.33041039448500015     
   16.365867754511768      -0.22063749432500010     
   16.511991573748478      -0.12956561664999997
   16.658115392985192      -6.2520931050000061E-002
   16.804239212221901      -2.0474291900000007E-002
   16.950363031458615      -3.3802861749999864E-003
   17.096486850695324      -1.1236421675000005E-002
   17.242610669932041      -4.4293935437500001E-002
   17.388734489168755      -0.10291197632249992     
   17.534858308405465      -0.18681497748249989     
   17.680982127642178      -0.29264704324999974     
   17.827105946878888      -0.40844271439000052     
   17.973229766115601      -0.50809938749999994     
   18.119353585352311      -0.55706159005000022     
   18.265477404589028      -0.53426514450000007     
   18.411601223825738      -0.44999058192999997     
   18.557725043062451      -0.33683265428499992     
   18.703848862299161      -0.22573322450000011     
   18.849972681535874      -0.13362568075000000     
   18.996096500772584      -6.6342932249999972E-002
   19.142220320009297      -2.4975045235000021E-002
   19.288344139246014      -9.3829022500000001E-003
   19.434467958482724      -1.9370208699999975E-002
   19.580591777719437      -5.4959120624999996E-002
   19.726715596956147      -0.11625987367499999     
   19.872839416192861      -0.20263722292500017     
   20.018963235429570      -0.30991265800000006     
   20.165087054666284      -0.42447163175000008     
   20.311210873902997      -0.51843669877499976     
   20.457334693139710      -0.55769086224999975     
   20.603458512376420      -0.52495092840000057     
   20.749582331613134      -0.43469907825000020     
   20.895706150849843      -0.32059742052500018     
   21.041829970086557      -0.21181538367500022     
   21.187953789323267      -0.12320815802500000     
   21.334077608559983      -5.9446244649999966E-002
   21.480201427796697      -2.1174214224999988E-002
   21.626325247033407      -8.1263172499999904E-003
   21.772449066270120      -2.0123068274999968E-002
   21.918572885506830      -5.7280081410249997E-002
   22.064696704743543      -0.11983124174999996
```

with numpy array:

```
    data = []
    for line in open('profile_3.dat'):
        new = line.split()
        data.append(new)
    profile = np.array(data)

    plt.figure()
    
    x = profile[:,0]
    y = profile[:,1]
    
    plt.plot(x,y)
    plt.show()
```

[image: plot with numpy array]

with `numpy` matrix:

```
    data = []
    for line in open('profile_3.dat'):
        new = line.split()
        data.append(new)
    profile = np.matrix(data)
    
    plt.figure()
        
    x = profile[:,0]
    y = profile[:,1]
        
    plt.plot(x,y)
    plt.show()
```

[image: plot with numpy matrix]

It seems that when plot with `numpy` array, the graph is inverted and some data is misplaced.

Comment: In complément to the existing answer, numpy.matrix is deprecated, so you should stick with array.

Comment: just a simple question, what is the difference between a numpy matrix and a numpy array. I am a regular MATLAB user. So the data type in numpy is a bit confusing to me.

Comment: numpy matrix is a special case of array that has exactly 2D. It has some special methods to make it easier to work with 2D arrays (e.g. *A matrix is a specialized 2-D array that retains its 2-D nature through operations. It has certain special operators, such as * (matrix multiplication) and ** (matrix power)* cf. [`matrix`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.html) documentation). From the docs: *It is no longer recommended to use this class, even for linear algebra. Instead use regular arrays. The class may be removed in the future.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that problem is in strings vs numbers:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = []
for line in open('profile_3.dat'):
    new = line.split()
    data.append(new)
profile = np.array(data)

plt.figure()

x = profile[:,0].astype(np.float)
y = profile[:,1].astype(np.float)

plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

Plot for your data:
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. I thought it will automatically be float number when converting it to a numpy array